# Microsoft.Graph photo retrieve function

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Has anyone been able to get this line to work?

```
graphClient.Users["userAddress@email.com"].Photo.Content.Req‌​uest().GetAsync();
```

I get a timeout. Also didn't work as a REST Get.
Could it be a bug in the library?

Comment: Could you post a wireshark or fiddler trace for this call? I'd like to see what is traveling down the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This operation in version 1.0 supports only a user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes.

Please ensure that you were calling this REST using the **work or school** account and the user have the subscription like Office 365 that making the user own the mailbox.

After meeting above two requirements, this REST works well for me.

And if the user didn't have the mailbox, you can get the thumbnail photo for a specified user from the [thumbnailPhoto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUserThumbnailPhoto) property via Azure AD Graph. Here is the request for your reference:

```
GET: https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/thumbnailPhoto?api-version
```

Comment: Thank you Fei. I think I understand. I am not in a position to test it but I think you are saying that the user account is actually called a mailbox in Microsoft Graph. I thought Microsoft had advised developers to use Microsoft Graph as Azure AD Graph is receiving no further development. Yet there is not even an equivalent to thumbnailPhoto in Microsoft Graph? Rather worrying!

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such REST in Microsoft Graph. If you have any idea or feedback about Microsoft Graph, you can submit it from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).

Comment: A user account is not a mailbox, they are two different things. This photo just happens to be pulled from Exchange since it supports both the User and any Contacts that user might have as well.